# Raw Delete Query

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, delete-row

I'm about to pull my hair out... why wont this run?

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->query('DELETE FROM catalog_product_super_attribute WHERE product_id = 46');
```

When I run that query via command line, or phpmyadmin even, it executes just fine deleting all the rows HOWEVER when I try to run it using code it doesn't work. I've even tried just bypassing Magento hoping it was something with them BUT when I tried to delete using straight mysql or mysqli in php it wouldn't work either.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be AWESOME.

Comment: Any error messages would help us to help you...

Comment: I'm not sure why "Magento" was removed from the title as it maybe an SQL question but its an SQL question about working within the confines of Magento.. I would think that that would be important information for someone wanting to click into my question and help out.

Comment: @Enriqe the only error messages I am seeing are `User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back` in the system.log file of magento

Comment: And have you tried to commit the transaction ? I hope you know what I'm talking about here.

Comment: @Enriqe I am sorry I do not... I will search though and find out what you mean :)

Comment: I'm not using Magento. But you need to `commit the transaction` for changes in your DB (like deleting rows) to take effect. Try to search for "how to commit transaction in Magento". Good luck :)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283010/magento-database-transaction

Comment: Actually just ran across that example and tried it out and it didnt work =\ I am wondering if for some reason or some how I'm locked from being able to delete from that table idk... at first I thought it might be a key constraint but when I run the code in phpmyadmin it runs just fine. ugh

Comment: BAM @Enriqe you were pretty much write... post an answer using the solution found here (not its the second answer that is correct) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953697/magento-data-is-not-inserted-into-database-but-the-id-is-autoincremented and i'll marke your answer as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$transaction = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

try {
    $transaction->beginTransaction();

    $transaction->query('DELETE FROM catalog_product_super_attribute WHERE product_id = 46');

    $transaction->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollBack(); // if anything goes wrong, this will undo all changes you made to your database
}
```

Comment: Nononono the answer from here is what worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953697/magento-data-is-not-inserted-into-database-but-the-id-is-autoincremented ... with adding the `; commit;` to the end of the actual query itself :P

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer to what worked for me and then I can mark it as right?

Comment: This is the same. And it's shorter and it has also `try .. catch` block where you can catch any errors and undo any changes that have been done to your database.

Comment: But do what you want to do. What is important I gave you the right kick to go :) - now you can mark my answer :)

Comment: When I tried this it didnt work though.. I had to use `; commit;`

Comment: `; commit;` ?? What is it? You mean some `$connection->commit();` probably - which is what I gave you in my answer.

Comment: nope i had to run this one for it to work `DELETE FROM catalog_product_super_attribute WHERE product_id = 46; commit;` for some reason doing `$connection->commit();` was not working for me